# python callback is still blocking

Tags: python, callback

From what I have read, callbacks are non-blocking. The function passed as a callback begins to execute even as the enclosing function has not completed. But I am missing something. In this example:

```
def func1(x, callback):
    print(x)
    for _ in range(100000000):
        continue
    print("done counting to hundred million")
    callback()

def func2():
    for _ in range(10000000):
        continue
    print("counted to 10 million")

func1("starting to count to hundred million",func2)
```

func1 counts to a hundred million (to simulate a lagging network socket or other process). I thought func2 would execute before func1 completes, but it does not. Obviously I have misunderstood the asynchronous nature of callbacks. Are they asynchronous and how am I missing this?

Comment: First of all your code isn't multi-threading or multi-tasking. Even if it was, the callback wouldn't start execution until it was called, which would be after the `for` loop in `func1()` has finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, callbacks are not asynchronous by default. Many asynchronous APIs *use* callbacks, but callbacks by their nature do not imply asynchronous behavior. In your example, you're just passing the `func2` function object to `func1` like you would any other type of object, and then you actually call it in a synchronous way after iterating over your `range` object, the same way you would call a normal function. The fact that you passed the function object as an argument to `func1` has no special meaning.

You're probably thinking of asynchronous APIs that take callbacks as arguments here, like [`multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async). In that case, `multiprocessing.Pool` is designed to run a function in a worker process, and then asynchronously execute a `callback` in a background thread in the main process when the worker process completes. This is done using logic built into `multiprocessing.Pool` though, it doesn't just magically happen because the function takes an argument called `callback`.

Comment: Thank you dano. This video, https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7z0smic9FUk at about position 3:50, talks about putting the time consuming logic in the calling function. I did not understand why. There are other videos that talk about doing a net work request. And without callbacks, the user would experience a delay. If a callback is still a blocking object I don't see how they achieve that. Multiprocessing w pool etc was not used. I'll see if I can find those examples.

Comment: @aquagremlin The example you provided is similar to the first example from that video, in which the `callback` is executed *after* the addition occurs, just like your callback runs after the `for` loop finishes. The comment being made in the video at the time you pointed out is explaining when callbacks are useful - when you're doing some long *asynchronous* operation, and you want to do something when its done. The keyword there is **asynchronous**. In his example, `add` isn't actually asynchronous. You have to actually run `add` in an asynchronous way yourself, via threads or sub-processes.

Comment: @aquagremlin So the idea is, "I have this really long operation I need to run, and when its done I want to do something with the result. But I don't want to wait around for the operation to finish. I want to run it in the background". If you have this need, you run the operation in a background thread or process, and pass a `callback` to the function doing the operation, and have it execute the callback when its done with the long operation. In the meantime, your main thread/process can go on doing other things.

Comment: Aha. So the code in func1 has to manage the 'asynchronocity'. Or use an API that calls code that manages itself asynchronously.  Thank you. Now it makes sense that I realize my example was using javascript and the author of that video was probably thinking that func1 was making node.js calls (an intrinsically asynchronous framework )

Comment: @aquagremlin Right. I've only been talking about threads/processes, but this all applies to functions that do non-blocking I/O as part of asynchronous frameworks like node.js or `asyncio`, too.